# Mongodb group by user and month

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that's setup like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  user_id : ObjectId(),
  amount: 123
  date: Date()
}
```

What I'm trying to do is aggregate this down to a `$sum` on the amount, which is grouped by month and user_id.

I can group simply by month:

```
{ 
  $group : {
    _id : { $month: '$date' },
    amount : { $sum : '$amount' },
  }
}, 
{
  $project : {
    amount: '$amount',
    date: '$date'
  }
}
```

and can do the same by user, but I can't seem to break it down by user and then amounts by month.  The end result I'm looking for, would be something like this:

```
[{
 _id: user_id,
 total: 123,
 months: [{
   '2015-10' : 100,
   '2015-09' : 23
 }]
}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
      db.stacks.insert({
      user_id : 1,
      amount: 100
      date: new Date('Sep 04, 2014')
    })

    {
      user_id : 1,
      amount: 12
      date: new Date('Oct 04, 2014')
    }

   db.invent.aggregate([
          {$group:{"_id": {date: "$date",user_id: "$user_id"},
            sum_by_date: {"$sum": "$amount"}
          }},
          {$group:{
            "_id": "$_id.user_id",
            total_sum: {"$sum": "$sum_by_date"},
            months:{"$push":"$_id.date"},   
          }}
        ])
```

result :{ "_id" : 1, "total_sum" : 112, "months" : [ ISODate("2007-04-16T18:30:00Z"), ISODate("2007-03-16T18:30:00Z") ] }

note:it is not fully complete ,trying to push $_id.date and  $sum_by_date together.